# With Fedora 22, Eclipse Pop-up window colors are black-on-black or white-on-light-gray

Tags: eclipse, colors, background, content-assist, eclipse-mars

I'm using Eclipse Mars.1 on Fedora 22 (with KDE).

When I hover on an identifier, the definition pop-up appears, but it's black on black. Example:

[image]

and when I Ctrl+Space for the Content Assist, the dialog appears, but the highlighted item is white-on-light-gray. Example:

[image]

I tried changing the "Content Assist" background in the Editor Colors dialog, in the preferences, but to no avail. How can I fix this?